# Did I instantiate an object of void?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

As you all know, in C# we could not do something like this:

```
var voidObject = new void();
```

or

```
var voidObject = new System.Void();
```

or

```
var voidObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(void));
```

But this code compiles successfully and in debug mode I can see that type of the `voidObject` is `System.Void`:

```
var voidObject = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(void));
```

What is this? Is this real instance of `void`?

Comment: Wow... Totally useless but incredible :-) They forgot to close that route :-)

Comment: I got this `Expression has been evaluated and has no value`

Comment: On .NET https://dotnetfiddle.net/BUUdKU and on Mono https://ideone.com/LegWvM

Comment: Why do you need object of void?

Comment: @Blam just because I can, I guess :)

Comment: `"Real instance of void?"` I guess you could call it that. If you call `.GetType()` on it you will get back `System.Void`. `void` is an alias of the `System.Void` struct. It has no functionality besides the methods inherited from `object`. Why would you even want to do this? I can't see a practical use case.

Comment: You can also create boxed `ArgIterator` and `TypedReference` with this. ☺

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see it is a perfectly good, perfectly valid ***boxed*** `System.Void` value type :-)

You can

```
Console.WriteLine(voidObject.GetType());
```

and see that it is a `System.Void`.

`System.Void` is a value type, so creating it through `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` should be equal to doing `(object)default(void)` (because `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` will return a value type with all its fields set to their default value) (note that clearly `(object)default(void)` is illegal).

Still there are not many things you can do with your *boxed* `System.Void`...

```
var voidObject = System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(void));
var voidObject2 = System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(void));

Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", voidObject.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("IsValueType: {0}", voidObject.GetType().IsValueType);

Console.WriteLine("Equals: {0}", voidObject.Equals(voidObject2));
Console.WriteLine("GetHashCode1: {0}", voidObject.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("GetHashCode2: {0}", voidObject2.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("ToString: {0}", voidObject.ToString());
```

There seems to be some differences between [.NET](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KYNuLv) and [Mono](https://ideone.com/chFtWt) implementations... On .NET all the instances of `System.Void` have the same `GetHashCode()`, while on Mono every one of them has a different `GetHashCode()`. The `Equals` works correctly (`true`) for both of them.

(note that the difference in the `GetHashCode()` seems to be a bug of Mono with `struct`s without fields: https://ideone.com/t0t8I6 that [should be fixed](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17577) in newer releases)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Imstance is the whrong word I guess. If you create an object by using `GetUninitializedObject` you get an unitialized object as mentioned rom methods name. So assume you have a class `Foo` with some members none of those members would have any value because the constructor is not called. While `Void` not even has any constructor you may not call `Activator.CreateInstance` on it or use `new void()`. However with the mentioned approach that does not use any constructor you create an object of it but leave it unitialized. So this is just a special case of leaving a new object unititialzed.

If this is a bug, a feature or whatever I can only guess.

EDIT: Obviosuly it´s a feature, the following from MSDN lets me assume so:

> The current method should only be used for deserialization when the user intends to immediately populate all fields. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So while you CAN create an instance using this method you should only do it when providing all necessary information immediatly after the call. However hence `void` does not have any members its state is still invalid.